# Data formatting using string spanning

Tags: java, performance, android, formatting

I would like to know how to make my code better. I'm still a newbie in Android, so any tips are appreciated.

The code is an AsyncTask class extender that formats data into a nice looking Spannable String. It works, but it's quite slow, even if ran on a background thread.

```
//SlideContentType is an enumerable with 4 options: Movie, Action, Game, Music
//SlideContent is a class that stores info about a specific movie/song/game etc...
public class PickCardAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<SlideContent.SlideContentType, List<SlideContent>>, Integer, Pair<SpannableStringBuilder, String>> {

    @Override
    protected Pair<SpannableStringBuilder, String> doInBackground(Pair<SlideContent.SlideContentType, List<SlideContent>>... pairs){

        //Get a reference to the list of all Slide Contents containing movies/games/etc.
        List<SlideContent> list = (List<SlideContent>) pairs[0].second;

        //Select a random item in the list
        Random random = new Random();
        random.setSeed(System.nanoTime());
        int randomNr = random.nextInt(list.size());
        SlideContent currentContent = list.get(randomNr);

        //The link and the content are released as a pair
        String websiteLink = currentContent.movieWebsite;

        //End result variable
        SpannableStringBuilder coloredString = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        //Do the appropriate actions
        if(pairs[0].first == SlideContent.SlideContentType.Movie){

            //Format the information from the Slide Content into a nice looking Spannable String
            SpannableString text = new SpannableString(currentContent.movieTitle);
            text.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            coloredString.append(text);

            coloredString.append(" (" + currentContent.movieYear + ")\n");

            text = new SpannableString(currentContent.movieGenres);
            text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.7f), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            coloredString.append(text);
            coloredString.append("\n");

            text = new SpannableString(currentContent.movieDescription);
            text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            coloredString.append(text);
            coloredString.append("\n");

            text = new SpannableString("Movie rated " + currentContent.movieRating + " out of 10.");
            text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.7f), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            coloredString.append(text);

        }
        //Return a pair of the Spannable String Builder and the link to the related website
        return new Pair<>(coloredString, websiteLink);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Random random = new Random();
random.setSeed(System.nanoTime());
```

Don't put this inside here. I'm assuming that this method will end up being called more than once. If so, you don't want to be seeding and re-seeding the `Random` every call.

`random` should be moved to a field of the class. Also, I don't think you need to manually call `Random.setSeed`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java/363692#363692) for more details.

---

I don't know my Java 100%, but I think this might be a typo:

```
Pair<SlideContent.SlideContentType, List<SlideContent>>... pairs
```

I think it should be:

```
Pair<SlideContent.SlideContentType>, List<SlideContent>... pairs
```